# How to apply Anti Aliasing in TImage component with PNG image in real time on Delphi?

Tags: delphi

I've created an application to display a transparent logo on the screen.

The purpose of this program is to display a logo during multimedia presentations on big screens.

The structure I used in this app is the same as a splash screen.

[image]

The difference is that I can switch between transparency mode and form mode by double-clicking the image so that I can resize the logo.

Here is an example of an execution.

[image]

The problem, as the image is in a Timage component, it appears with serrated.

[image]

Is it possible to apply anti aliasing on the Timage component while maintaining image quality when resizing?

Comment: No. You cannot maintain image quality when resizing an image. If you want to preserve quality, draw vector graphics.

Comment: @Victoria But when we have a large image, and we resize to a smaller size, we can maintain quality in bitmaps. I'm sure have a way to apply anti aliasing, just do not know how it does in Delphi. If I have a png image of 6000x2000px and reduce it to 1000x200px, I do not lose any quality. O problema é que em delphi, qualquer tamanho que eu reduza, a imagem fica serrilhada. I know there is a way to avoid this because I've seen apps done in delphi so. I just do not know how they did it.

Comment: Surely you will lose quality. It's impossible to resize raster graphics without distortion. There are algorithms that can make the result look better, but they cannot be lossless.

Comment: You can convert the PNG to an ICO file and load it with LoadIconWithScaleDown to the desired size. Not sure if this gives better results.

Comment: Image quality of VCL `TImage` is pretty bad. Your only option is to use other graphic library (e.g. GDI+) for resizing or even create yor own component with it.

Comment: We don't know how you are currently resizing the image. But yes, using a library with more advanced sampling algorithms than Delphi has built in would likely be the solution.

Comment: For VCL you can use `SetStretchBltMode(dc, HALFTONE)` and `StretchBlt`. I can't remember if it supports alpha channel (likely it should). For library I recommend `Graphics32`: https://github.com/graphics32

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. I'm still doing some tests, and analyzing your suggestions. So far everything I've done has not worked out yet. Maybe it will take me a few days to get back with a final solution. But if anyone still has new suggestions, I'd love to get to know them.